# Why did ravana send his warriors one by one?

Tags: ramayana, rama, ravana

Ravana was a good tactician . He sent Indrajit first to destroy the army .He started realising that Rama is no usual warrior so he deliberately woke kumbhakarna up .
But he never sent a combination of warriors to attack sri rama together . In that case his probability to win would have been more .

Was narayan talking to him in his own method that come home dear its too long you have been in the pain of bandhan ? 
Was narayan crushing his ego slowly ?

Comment: Please ask only one question.

Comment: I expected one answer will be having answers to all the questions .

Comment: From which scripture you are asking Q? As per [Valmiki Ramayana: Yuddha Kanada: Sarga37](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga37/yuddha_37_frame.htm) all important warriors were guarding Lanka.. At this point your Q looks unclear..